# Getting an error while installing pandas package in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting below error when I try to install the `pandas` package:

```
c:\Phython\Scripts>pip install c:\temp\pandas-0.23.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pandas-0.23.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

my python version is

> Python 3.7.0rc1 (v3.7.0rc1:dfad352267, Jun 12 2018, 07:05:25) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]

any trick for installing package?

Comment: Maybe that wheels for python 2.7?

Comment: If you install wheels, you need to make sure to use the ones for the correct version of python.

Comment: python 3.7 is not a stable release yet, downgrade to python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install Pandas for version 2.7  (-cp27 gives you this information)

c:\temp\pandas-0.23.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

You need a 3.x version instead to be compatible with your Python version.